# Magento Multistore - no pages showing apart from Home page

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

I managed to set up another store (subdirectory). **Home page** works perfectly fine however, **only home page is showing**. After clicking on any link on the website, every page says

```
Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I noticed that it is probably problem with URLs as every link on the website does not show the right path - it is showing

> http://127.0.0.1/name-of-the-page/

instead of

> http://127.0.0.1/name-of-the-folder/name-of-the-page/

Does anyone knows how I could solve this problem? I run out of options, I don't know what else to try to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably  you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server.
If the page `127.0.0.1/index.php/name-of-page` works then that's the problem.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869092/2047249) how you can enable `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick reply! I tried to put 127.0.0.1/index.php/name-of-page in the browser but it is taking me to http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/

I have the same problem with pages in first store as well.